# invalidate the session in Tapestry from JUnit tests

Tags: session, junit, tapestry

I am working on a large complicated Tapestry service.  It generally works but sometimes when running for a while the session it is in will get invalidated, and it will send an error.  There is nothing about this service that should need the session but sometimes it depends on a service that depends on a service that "needs" the session.

I want to pragmatically invalidate the session in my tests, so I can protect against regression.  Ideally I would do this without killing the session in the production code, which is how I am testing it now.

Specificly, we are testing the service by running the server and making http calls, and also by extending TapestryIoCTestCase.  I can't think of any clean way to invalidate a session from the http client tests.  and the Mock session created for TapestryIoCTestCase does not support invalidation.

I have looked into setting the session time-out in the tests, but I was hoping for something more direct.

Thanks

e for instance someone at somepoint wanted to set the locale in one of our dependencies

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: setAttribute: Session [31943F300613D2105C9AF8602397557D] has already been invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1437)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1402)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.setAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:156)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.SessionImpl.setAttribute(SessionImpl.java:67)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.SessionApplicationStatePersistenceStrategy.set(SessionApplicationStatePersistenceStrategy.java:68)
    at $ApplicationStatePersistenceStrategy_13c1cafe292.set($ApplicationStatePersistenceStrategy_13c1cafe292.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ApplicationStateManagerImpl$ApplicationStateAdapter.set(ApplicationStateManagerImpl.java:50)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ApplicationStateManagerImpl.set(ApplicationStateManagerImpl.java:138)
    at $ApplicationStateManager_13c1cafe272.set($ApplicationStateManager_13c1cafe272.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the `HttpSession` which can be invalidated by calling `HttpSession.invalidate()`. Though in all honesty your question provides too little information for a proper answer. What is your setup? What have you tried? What does your code look like? Are you mocking your Servlet Container? Etc...

Questions without code are hard to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added more details.  I think the main issue is remotely invalidating the session from test code.

Comment: Still too little to go by. Can you share the error (stacktrace) you describe with "and it will send an error". The combination of running your server and using TapestryTestCase sounds dodgy as well. This could mean you have a Mocked tapestry HttpSession and a real HttpSession floating around. Your goal should be to access the real HttpSession in your test and invalidate. But without any code I can't help with that.

Comment: The TapestryTestCase and the HTTP tests are separate, both have issues invalidating the the cache from the test.  The error is internal to our massive system, but stems from someone directly querying the session (for instance, getting or setting locale information).  I want to test against this type of situationist.